# Calculate surface area of the non-white areas in a binary thresholded image (python)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

What are possible ways to calculate the surface area of the non-white areas/gray/black patches in the image?  I have tried  `cv2.contours` to get the shapes, iterate on the contours and sum up the total area and perimeter using  `cv2.contours` and  `cv2.arcLength(contour,True)`  but results don't seem to correlate with the image.

I also tried adding a Canny Edge Detection before the contour but seems still don't work well.

[image: Result after global thresholding]

Just an additional context, I would like to use the surface areas as features to an ML model).

Answer (score 0):

You need [cv.countNonZero(img)](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa4b89393263bb4d604e0fe5986723914). Black pixels will have the value 0 and white/gray pixels will have bigger values. To find the number of non-white pixels, you have to invert the image before using countNonZero().

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('jwsFy.png', 0)
img = 255-img # invert image
n_black = cv2.countNonZero(img)

print("Number of dark pixels:")
print(n_black)

height, width = img.shape
n_total = height * width

print("Percentage of dark pixels:")
print(n_black / n_total * 100)
```